# How to Pivot in mysql

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

Hi all l'm new to pivoting & l'm experimenting with a simple table l want to pivot the following table with the below query

[image]

my pivoting sql query

```
SELECT fname, lname,
          sum(IF(agedescription = luckystar, agenumber, NULL)) AS luckystar,
          sum(IF(agedescription = pilchards, agenumber, NULL)) AS pilchards, 
          sum(IF(agedescription = nespresso, agenumber, NULL)) AS nespresso 
          FROM users
          GROUP BY fname;
```

and l face the below error

[image]

can anyone help me to achieve the following result

[image]

Comment: You have to put quotes around strings: `agedescription = 'luckystar'`

Comment: awesome thanks  but now l'm getting the "check the updated picture"